# how to add a Cancellation Token to a Task?

Tags: c#, task, cancellation-token

I am getting introduced to Task, and got this far:

In Main:

```
 Task<double> t = Task.Run(TW.DoingMegaFlops_Async);
```

Where in class TW:

```
 public async Task<double> DoingMegaFlops_Async()
 {...await ...; return 0.0;}
```

My concept console app builds and runs just fine.
The problem is how to expand this with a `Cancellation Token`. I tried this:

```
CancellationTokenSource wtokenSource= new CancellationTokenSource();
Task.Run(TW.DoingMegaFlops_Async(wtokenSource.Token), wtokenSource.Token);
```

and in the TW class:

```
public async void DoingMegaFlops_Async(CancellationToken wtoken)
{...await...; return;}
```

The build error in Main is:

```
Cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Action'
```

I have already fooled around with casting to (Action), but with no avail.
Actually, I do not really understand what I am doing here, so would like to learn from the forum.

As you see from the code snippets, I already cut down on the interface of the Async method by going to a return type of void. Don't know if that actually made things easier.

Comment: [Don't use async void](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/)

Comment: Indeed, I'd rather return some useful data. That's why I need the cancellation token, so that when the app stops, I can stop the task in a clean way, and show some task result data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Task.Run(TW.DoingMegaFlops_Async)` is "Method Group" shorthand for `Task.Run(() => TW.DoingMegaFlops_Async())` - it's allowed because you're calling a method with no parameters.

When calling a method with parameters, though, you must include it:

```
Task.Run(() => TW.DoingMegaFlops_Async(wtokenSource.Token), wtokenSource.Token);
```

Comment: Great, this indeed builds OK. This even allows for adding the return value. I am surprised to hear that I used a shorthand notation. Would it not be easier to avoid the lambda notation and to correct "my" notation? The "() =>" notation seems to me, I started with Fortran, somewhat like higher mathematics.